# Dragging more than one item in Adobe Flash CS3 Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, drag, adobe-flash-cs3

I've been trying to program a game in my class on Digital Media, and have run up to a huge roadblock concerning draggable items. I first managed to make one item that could be dragged with the mouse using this code (the movie clip is called 'honey'):

```
//set listeners
honey.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startHoneyDrag);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopHoneyDrag);
honey.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dragHoney);

//offset between sprite location and click
var clickOffset:Point = null;

//user clicked
function startHoneyDrag(event:MouseEvent) {
        clickOffset = new Point(event.localX, event.localY-7);
}

//user released
function stopHoneyDrag(event:MouseEvent) {
    clickOffset = null
}
//run every frame
function dragHoney(event:Event) {
    if (clickOffset != null) { // must be dragging
    honey.x = mouseX - clickOffset.x;
    honey.y = mouseY - clickOffset.y;
    }
}
```

However,making more than one moveable movie clip has proven impossible so far. Using the same code multiple times creates an error due to conflicting parts of the code. When I asked one of the better programming students, he told me to create an array, which I did;

```
var honeyBall:Array = new Array();
honeyBall = ["honey, honey1, honey2"];
```

But now I don't know how to make a code that would refer to a movie clip refer to an array of them. Help would be seriously appreciated, as these problems have been giving me serious trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
honeyBall = ["honey, honey1, honey2"];
```

This is array containing one string. You should get your instances of clips into array, something like this:

```
honeyBall = [honey1, honey2, honey3];
```

Then you drag it with

```
function dragHoney(event:Event) {
    if (clickOffset != null) {
        for each (var honey:DisplayObject in honeyBall) {
            honey.x = mouseX - clickOffset.x;
            honey.y = mouseY - clickOffset.y;
        }
    }
}
```

(will drag everything in array, be it one or several clips.)